# How to map out the user's entire computer

Tags: python, file, format, python-os, psutil

I am trying to make a video player app in python and instead of the user importing a file and then playing it, I wanted to map out the user's entire computer and format it so it would only pick the mp4 file and the user could easily choose it from the library. I tried implementing it and it kind of works but the method is not really to my liking. I used **psutil and os** to get everything that the user has but it is slow and the time it takes changes every time I run it. Here is my current code:

```
import psutil
import os


format = "mp4"
mp4_files = []
folders = [part.device.replace("\\", "/") for part in psutil.disk_partitions(all=True)]
def check_files():
    while folders:
        for path in folders:
            try:
                for file in os.listdir(path):
                    split = file.split('.')
                    if split[-1] == format:
                        mp4_files.append(path + file)
                    elif len(split) == 1:
                        folders.append(path + file + "/")
            except Exception:
                pass
            finally:
                folders.remove(path)

check_files()
print(mp4_files)
print(len(mp4_files))
# the rest of my code
```

I have seen programs that do this way faster, for example if you open up window's own apps, it doesn't even have a loading time. Another example is the countless music players. They load up and dynamically update the files in an instance. I also tried **numba** to speed up the process but as expected it did not work. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: [scandir](https://pypi.org/project/scandir/) may help speed things up. A lot of media players also restrict their scans to a subset of folders.

Comment: @JoshG scandir looks interesting but I tried itand it was actually slower than using listdir.

Comment: This operation is likely IO bound (especially on HDD which have a small amount of IOPS). When the OS put the directory structure in the cache, it should be much faster. How long do it takes? How many files are listed? You could eventually try `os.walk` but I do not think it will be much faster. Parallelism might help a bit on SSDs too (not on HDD).